# Javascript to check if a dynamically created checkbox is checked on a dynamically created button click

Tags: javascript

Due to some reasons i m dynamically creating a checkbox in a Grid..

Also i m dynamically creating a Button in the same Grid.

On this particular button click i need to check if the checkboxes are checked or not.

If the checkboxes are checked i should uncheck it.and vice versa.

Is it possible to achieve this in javascript?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Is that the entirety of your question?

Comment: yes.....................

Comment: In other words, you didn't actually **ask** a question that required more than a yes/no response. If you have a *specific* question about *how* to do this, then we'll be positively glad to help if you show us what you have so far, and explain exactly where you think it's gone wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

```
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click",function(){
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'),function(el){
        el.checked = !el.checked   //Invert
    });​
}, false);
```

No matter the checkboxes are created dynamically or not, this code will still work because it does not even need any `id` or `class`.

For IE:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
    var ele = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++){
        if(ele[i].type == "checkbox"){
            el.checked = !el.checked   //Invert
        }
    }
});
```

Ultimate jQuery solution!

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
        this.checked = !this.checked;
    }
});
```

**LIVE DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/jfeAd/

Comment: Note that IE 8 in quirks mode and IE 7 and lower do not have support for `querySelector`. Also there is no requirement in any standard for navtive methods to support host objects as their `this` object. So calling such methods on DOM objects (like the NodeList used here) can be expected to (and do) throw errors in conforming browsers. Try it in IE 8 and lower.

Comment: Also, this function only uncheckes the checked ones, it doesn't check the unchecked ones per the OP.

Comment: Keep trying, *addEventListener* is not supported by IE 8 and lower. And what feature test(s) are you planning to use to chose which version of the code to run?

Comment: @RobG - I hate IE! jQuery is my final weapon.

Comment: For those who have been programming for the web for some time, IE 8 (and even 7 and 6) is a snap compared to the days of IE 4 and NN4. :-)

Comment: I can't imagine those days how do people write their javascripts... in IE4

Answer (score 0):

You can collect checkboxes within a certain context (some contianer within the grid) and set their checked property to the opposite of whatever it currently is, so:

```
var grid = <something that returns a reference to the grid>
var cb, cbs = grid.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (var i=0, iLen=cbs.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  cb = cbs[i];
  if (cb.type == 'checkbox') {
    cb.checked = !cb.checked;
  }
}
```